# How to check whether any variable is passed through URL or not?

Tags: php

I want to pass a variable (`foo=bar`) to URL.
If the URL has already a variable, then `foo` should be appended to current URL with `&` and `foo=bar`.
But if the address bar does not have any variable, then the current URL should be appended with `?` and `foo=bar`

So how can I check whether any variable is present in current URL or not?

Comment: Can you restate your question, maybe provide an example of what you're doing and what is failing? It is difficult to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Variables passed in the URL are called `GET` parameters.  You can retrieve them with PHP by using the `$_GET` array.

Given the URL - `http://mycoolsite.com?foo=bar&stack=overflow`

Doing a `print_r()` on `$_GET` would give you -

```
Array ( 
  [foo] => bar 
  [stack] => overflow 
)
```

Once you have this array, you can test the existence of a certain variable using the `in_array()` function.

```
if (in_array('foo',$_GET)){
  // the foo variable is was passed
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply iterate over all of the parameters you were passed and examine then that way -

```
foreach($_GET AS $key=>$value){
  // $key = the name of the variable
  // $value = the value of the variable
}
```

---

Resources

- `$_GET` - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
- `in_array()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: but i dont know which variable is passed

Comment: @Lix: given that the question mentions `?` and `&`, it might be about passing additional arguments *into* a URL being built, e.g. `echo $my_base_url . '?foo=' . urlencode($bar)` would be incorrect if `$my_base_url` already includes a query string.

Comment: @dco - Yes... Indeed this might be the case.  However I can only answer a question with the provided information.  My answer was directed at this question - `"...So how can i check wether any variable are passed in address bar or not."`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to pass var=foo and stack=overflow variables to the current URL. In other words, you want to redirect the user to current address + your new variables. You could try this:

```
$url = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos("?", $url) !== FALSE){
    $url .= "&var=foo&stack=overflow";
}else{
    $url .= "?var=foo&stack=overflow";
}

header("Location: ".$url);
exit();
```

It gets the current URL, checks if it already has a `?` in it. If yes, it appends the `var` & stack with a `&`, otherwise with a `?` and `&` accordingly.

Comment: I like your choice of variables ;)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is :

```
$url = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if(strpos($url, "?") !== FALSE){
            $url .= "&var=foo&stack=overflow"; 
}else{

 $url .= "?var=foo&stack=overflow"; 
}

header("Location: ".$url); 
exit();
```

strpos reversed order ;)
This is an example:

```
$mystring = 'abc'; 
$findme   = 'a'; 
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
```